# adb unauthorized android marshmallow

Tags: android, adb, rsa, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have attempted every fix that has come up with no success.  Of the things i have attempted:

1. Turn on/off usb debugging
2. use different cables
3. use different computers
4. uninstall and reinstall drivers
5. remove any other instances of adb
6. adb is not in my PATH, I navigate to the file directly
7. delete keys from the .android folder (keys show up in there every time I run adb)
8. Remove the key from /data/misc/adb on the phone (now no keys even seem to generate)
9. push adbkey to /data/misc/adb/ on the phone

I have even gone as far as to remove any tethering apps, SideSync, anything that needs a connection to the computer.

There is no button in developer options "Revoke USB debugging authorization" and no matter what I do, there is no popup for RSA.  I don't know why i get adbkey and adbkey.pub in my .android folder whenever I start adb.  I also don't know why they haven't generated on my phone after I deleted them.

I am using:
windows 10 64 bit
Samsung Android ADB Interface driver v. 2.12.4.0
adb version 1.0.36
Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (T-Mobile) with android 6.0.1

I am rooted and have a different kernel (beastmode 3.1.40) so I can use viper4android

I have exhausted just about every avenue I can think of (short of wiping my phone/computer, which i refuse to do at least for the computer, hence why I tried different computers), please let me know if you can think of anything else.

Comment: SO is not the place to discuss problems with *custom* ROMs. if something does not work - revert to the stock ROM

Comment: I have the same problem with an Galaxy Note 4 phone rooted with Dr. Ketan M4 ROM (Android Marshmallow). When I connect the device to USB, and i type adb devices, I can find only the unauthorized device. 
Killing the server, and restarting does not solve the problem.
Also, turning Off and On the USB Debugging options in the phone does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to kill `adb` `kill server` and `start-server` again.

> You can find the adb tool in `<sdk>`/platform-tools/.`

here `<sdk>` : Path to your android sdk on your machine.Go to `platform-tools` folder and try below commands.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Hope it works for you..

Comment: I do that every time I do anything, but nada